# What, if any, IRA options are permitted with my high salary?

Tags: united-states, 401k, ira, roth-ira, retirement-plan

I am single, and make more money (more than $200k) than any of the limits I've seen for contributions or deductions for either Roth or traditional IRAs.  My employer has a 401k plan.

I currently do not have an IRA (other than a rollover IRA from my 401k from a previous employer).  I do have a 401k with my current employer.

Given this info, am I permitted to open and contribute anything to either kind of IRA?  The way I am reading things:

1. I cannot contribute to a Roth IRA
2. I cannot deduct contributions to a traditional IRA, but I can contribute up to $5500 (post-tax)

Is this correct?  If so, is there any reason to contribute to a traditional IRA?  Are there other retirement options (besides my existing 401k) for someone with my salary?

Comment: Did you check whether your employer's 401(k) plan offers a *traditional* post-tax contribution option? This kind of post-tax contribution pre-dates the Roth option and is still available in some plans. Your traditional post-tax contributions wouldn't be limited by the $17,500 limit. Rather, there's a combined limit of $51,000 (in 2014) for employee pre-tax, Roth, traditional post-tax, & employer contributions. While you wouldn't get a tax deduction for traditional post-tax contributions, earnings on that money would benefit from tax deferral, and the post-tax basis can be withdrawn tax-free.

Comment: Here's a [link with more information on the traditional post-tax option](http://www.bogleheads.org/wiki/After-tax_401%28k%29) ... Quote: *"Section 415(c)(1)(A) limits total contributions to defined contribution plans to $50,000 in 2012. The limit for an after-tax 401k is the difference between the amount already contributed by the employer and employee, and the Section 415 limit."*

Comment: (p.s. I suggest you check your 401(k)'s summary plan description document for a definitive answer.)

Answer (score 4):

Does your current 401(k) have low fees and good investment choices? If so you might be able to "roll-in" your rollover IRA to your 401(k), then do a [backdoor Roth IRA contribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roth_IRA#Traditional_IRA_conversion_as_a_workaround_to_Roth_IRA_income_limits). A Roth IRA would be *far* more useful than a non-deductible traditional IRA.

Answer (score 3):

"I currently do not have an IRA (other than a rollover IRA from my 401k from a previous employer)" The source is irrelevant. You have an IRA. 
The reason to keep contributing is that at some point, you might transfer the pretax dollars into a 401(k) and the post tax dollars can be converted to Roth.

Other than the above, investing in a standard brokerage account (a non-retirement account) has its positives. Gains can see long term cap gain treatment, and the assets see a step-up in basis when you die.

Comment: IMHO, "post-tax" is ambiguous.  Did you specifically mean a plain investment account with a broker or mutual fund dealer?  The mention of capital gains seems to imply so. FWIW, when I see "post tax", my brain also wants to think about the traditional post-tax contribution option available in some (but not all) employer 401(k) plans, and Roth-type accounts.

Comment: Edited to correct. Agreed, Roth is post tax, as is non-deducted IRA. Bad choice of words.

Comment: No problem. Did get me thinking about whether the OP considered if his 401(k) plan allows traditional (non-Roth) post-tax contributions. Sometimes an option. Higher limit.